# Display records based on multiple conditions

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a list of records that I iterate over.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var=item">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.field__c == v.completed}">

        <c:item item="{!item}"/>

    </aura:if>
 </aura:iteration>
```

I have multiple conditions to display the data in different ways

Personal Items

1. Display current == true, personal == true of the ownerId == currentUserId (current personal items).
2. Display current == false, personal == true of the  of the ownerId == currentUserId (completed personal items).

Shared records among the org

3. Display current == true, personal == false (current company items).
4. Display current == false, personal == false (completed company items).

I'm using a mix of conditional database calls, conditional css, and aura:if's. It's turning into a big mess making it all work together.

Are conditional database calls, conditional css, and aura:if's the only ways to control which records are shown?

If I embed multiple aura:if's it causes rendering errors with my lightning events.

Is there a best practice from Salesforce how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce actually recommend using CSS if possible:

> Use CSS to toggle markup visibility. You could use the  tag to do the same thing but we recommend using CSS as it’s the more standard approach.

Reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm#js_cb_show_hide_markup).

To use CSS, you can put something like this in your CSS file:

```
.THIS .hide {
  display:none!important;
}
```

And add the hide class where necessary.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var=item">
    <c:item item="{!item}" itemClass="{!item.field__c == v.completed ? hide : ''}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

In the `item` component, you can then map itemClass to whatever class you need.

ie:

```
<aura:attribute name="itemClass" type="String"/>
<ui:outputText value="{!v.item}" class="{!v.itemClass}"/>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know

Comment: You should be able to put more complicated logic in the class attribute if necessary

Comment: Oh and here is a nice reference to the kinds of things you can have in the class expression - quite a lot of good ones actually: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm

Comment: components don't let you use a class attribute. I guess I need to use an aura:id?

Comment: Normally you can define 2-3 classes on the component - they are generally different for each component. For example, `ui:button` has `class` and `labelClass`. If this is your own custom component, you can make an attribute - perhaps `itemClass` and pass that to the inner component.

Comment: <aura:attribute name="itemClass" type="String"/> like this? In the inner component.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. Then map that to your inner class.

Comment: Not sure how to do that

<c:item item="{!item}" itemClass="{!item.field__c == v.personal ? hide : ''}"/>

Like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42810/discussion-between-tyler-zika-and-caspar-harmer).

Comment: Yes - sorry, I'm out of time - you should be able to find all this stuff in the developer guide.